# Integration of step functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis, riemann-integration

[image]

I've managed parts (a) and (b) fairly easily, but c is causing me a real headache. I've seen the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality before, but I've hit a roadblock because I've no idea whether or not I can conclude that I(phi^2) is less than or equal to (I(phi))^2, which I need in order to get the result Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

If $\phi$ is a step function, i.e., $\phi= \Sigma_{i=1}^n c_i\chi_i$ , then

$\phi $ is Riemann integrable, so it is Lebesgue integrable, so that

$\phi \in L^1$, so Cauchy-Schwarz applies:

$$ \int (\phi) (\phi)= \int  \phi^2 \leq \int \phi \int \phi= (\int \phi )^2 $$

If you have not seen Lebesgue integration, then you can use the fact that the space of Riemann-integrable functions are an inner-product space (see* for a caveat) with inner-product given as above, i.e., $<f,g>:= \int fg$, and then apply Cauchy-Schwarz.

- The problem with Riemann integrable functions as a normed space is that we may have $||f||:= (\int f^2)^{1/2}=0$ without t$f$ being $0$, but this is not a problem in your situation, and you may work with Riemann-integrable functions as an inner-product space and apply Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: I haven't even studied Lebesgue integration yet.

Comment: If you know Cauchy-Schwarz, then the space of integrable functions is an inner-product space with inner-product defined by $<f,g>:= \int fg$. Then you can use Cauchy -Schwarz on $<\phi, \phi>:= \int \phi^2$. You can assume the fact that every Riemann-integrable function is Lebesgue -integrable, or just use the subspace of Riemann integrable functions. Does that work for you?

Comment: @gary Something does not look quite right.  The C-S inequality is $|<f,g>|^2 \le ||f||^2||g||^2$.  With $f=g=\phi$, we have $|<\phi ,\phi>|^2=(\int \phi^2)^2 \le \int \phi^2 \int \phi^2=(\int \phi^2)^2$ does not reveal much.